# How to encrypt the password using seed method?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, encryption, seeding

I want to encrypt the password stored in Seed method with SimpleCrypto.

Here is the init class.

```
protected override void Seed(MainContext context)
    {
        Role role1 = new Role { RoleName = "Admin" };
        Role role2 = new Role { RoleName = "User" };


        User user1 = new User  { Email = "admin@gmail.com", UserId = 1, Firstname = "Admin", ImageSrc = "batman.gif", Surname = "test", Password = "123456", PasswordSalt="", IsActive = true, CreateDate = DateTime.UtcNow, Roles = new List<Role>() };
        User  user2 = new User  { Email = "user1@ymail.com", UserId = 2, Firstname = "User", ImageSrc = "batman.gif", Surname = "test", Password = "eee", PasswordSalt="", IsActive = true, CreateDate = DateTime.UtcNow, Roles = new List<Role>() };




        user1.Roles.Add(role1);
        user2.Roles.Add(role2);

        context.Users.Add(user1);
        context.Users.Add(user2);

        context.SaveChanges();
        }
```

I really don't know how to bind this together.

Any suggestion?

Comment: why not use in-built UserManager to do that?

Comment: Do you want to encrypt the password with a symmetrical scheme, or hash the password (implied by your snippet, and generally recommended)?

Comment: @CoOl Do you have an example of that? Using UserManager.

Comment: @RonBrogan. Both. As on my registration page i have used SimpleCrypto as encryption. I also want to use it in Seed method to.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```
public class CustomPasswordHasher : IPasswordHasher
{

    public string HashPassword(string password, string salt)
    {
        //Using SHA1 (Any other method can be used here)
        SHA1 sha1 = System.Security.Cryptography.SHA1.Create();
        byte[] inputBytes = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(salt + password + salt);
        byte[] hash = sha1.ComputeHash(inputBytes);
        return Convert.ToBase64String(hash);
    }

    public PasswordVerificationResult VerifyHashedPassword(string hashedPassword, string providedPassword)
    {
        providedPassword = HashPassword(providedPassword);
        return (providedPassword == hashedPassword ? PasswordVerificationResult.Success : PasswordVerificationResult.Failed);
    }
}
```

and call it in the constructor like this:

```
 var ph = new CustomPasswordHasher();
 this.PasswordHash = ph.HashPassword(this.Password, this.PasswordSalt);
```